# Spring data mongo can't save GeoData b/c of No property type found

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When trying to update an object with geoData spring data mongo throws the ff exception

`org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property type found on org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonGeometryCollection!`

an example object structure is like this

```
class Location{
    ....
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    GeoJsonGeometryCollection geomerty
}
```

repository

```
interface LocationRepository extends MongoRepository<Location, String> {

}
```

the save method (which is called on update)

```
//the exception is thrown here
locationRepository.save(updatedLocation)
```

I haven't added the type field, it is added by **GeoJsonGeometryCollection** conveter .

Any workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working when I upgraded my spring boot version from 1.3 to 1.4